# how to upload image with jodit-react using axios

Tags: reactjs

It says connection error. I have read the document under the link https://chowdera.com/2021/01/20210121161512693f.html
and there is no documentation regarding axios to upload image with jodit-react.
I don't know what to do, please help me. Thanks

```
const config = {
        readonly: false,
        editHTMLDocumentMode: true,
        uploader: {
          url: URL + "upload-image",
          headers: authHeaderAdmin(),
    
          filesVariableName: function (i) {
            return "imgs[" + i + "]";
          },
          withCredentials: false,
          pathVariableName: "path",
          format: "json",
          method: "POST",
          prepareData: function (formData) {
            var file = formData.getAll("files[0]")[0];
            formData.append("file", file);
            console.log("formData 22: ", formData);
            return formData;
          },
          isSuccess: function (resp) {
            return !resp.error;
          },
          getMessage: function (resp) {
            return resp.msgs.join("\n");
          },
          process: function (resp) {
            return resp;
          },
          
        },
      };
    
    {useMemo(
              () => (
                <JoditEditor
                  ref={editor}
                  value={content}
                  config={config}
                  tabIndex={1} // tabIndex of textarea
                  onBlur={(newContent) => {
                    // setContent(newContent.target.innerHTML);
                  }}
                  onChange={(newContent) => {
                    setContent(newContent);
                  }}
                />
              ),
              []
            )}
```

Comment: what is the error log? please share with us.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the API side of things. I was able to use your code almost as is and my jodit-react module is uploading my images. Thanks for that btw!

I was facing `400: Bad request` response from my API cause the form data being sent has extra keys. I removed them and viola! my images are being uploaded and I get a response.

```js
url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/question/upload`,
prepareData: function (formData) {
  var file = formData.getAll('files[0]')[0]
  formData.delete('files[0]')
  formData.append('files', file)
  formData.delete('path')
  formData.delete('source')
  return formData
},
```